# Multiple checkbox and Textarea

Tags: javascript

I have multiple checkboxes that the user can select to add values to a textarea. However, how do I make the output come out with commas in between and a period in the end? Thanks.

value1, value2, value3.

Comment: You'll need to show your HTML code.  Also, you'll get a better response if you accept answers to your earlier questions.

Comment: ok, thanks. Went ahead and did that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, then output them with a join. i.e.

```
// establish an array to collect the selected values
var selValues = [];

// test for selected boxes. When/if selected (checked), add their value
// to the array with the .push() method
if (selectBox1.checked)
  selValues.push(selectBox1.value);
if (selectBox2.checked)
  selValues.push(selectBox2.value);
if (selectBox3.checked)
  selValues.push(selectBox3.value);

// now selValues has a list of selected values. Use the .join()
// method to take those values and concatenate them with a comma,
// then add a period to the end.
textArea1.value = selValues.join(',') + '.';
```

*Above is pseudo-code, not production code.*

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this dynamically: http://jsfiddle.net/NSctv/.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() { // when clicked...
    $('textarea').val( // set value
        $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).toArray().join(", ") + '.' // set value to checked values concatenated with ", " and a dot.
    );
});
```